# How do i add the following code in my node.js without breaking the other code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So i have the following code in my node.js server,

```
var socket = require( 'socket.io' );
var express = require( 'express' );
var https = require( 'https' );
var fs = require('fs');

var app = express();

var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('', 'utf8');
var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};

var server = https.createServer(credentials, app );

var io = socket.listen( server);
io.set('transports',['xhr-polling']);
io.sockets.on( 'connection', function( client ) {
    console.log( "New client !" );

    client.on( 'message', function( data ) {
        console.log( 'Message received ' + data.name + ":" + data.message );
        //client.broadcast.emit( 'message', { name: data.name, message: data.message } );
        io.sockets.emit( 'message', data);
    });

    client.on( 'doTrade', function( data ) {
        //console.log( 'Message received ' + data.name + ":" + data.message );
        io.sockets.emit( 'doTrade', data );
    });
});

server.listen( (x) );
```

I want to add the following to display the amount of connected users.

```
io.sockets.on("connection", socket => {
  let clientCount = io.engine.clientsCount;

  io.sockets.emit("user count", clientCount);
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    io.sockets.emit("user count", clientCount);
  });
});
```

***https://juandiego.co/blog/show-connected-users-socketio-vuejs/***

When adding this directly, it breaks the other components due to the double calling of 'connection'?

How would i properly integrate this?

Comment: First off, adding a new event handler for the `connection` event is perfectly fine.  That, by itself, doesn't break anything so if something is breaking, that probably has more to do with the code itself or how you are adding it to your project, not the fact that there's a second event handler for the `connection` event`.

Comment: What is the EXACT error (word for word) that you get when you add this code?  And, what exact line of code does the error refer to.  I'm wondering if `io.engine` is no longer support in socket.io.

Comment: Also, this code is kind of silly because the message you emit on the `disconnect` event is ALWAYS going to be the same as the message you emit when they connect because you have a local copy of `clientCount` which will never change.

Comment: the npm-debug.log is empty after adding the code & restarting it, but it definitely breaks the other code. The other code is meant to live update charts & orderbooks, which no longer works after the restart.

Comment: Well, you can't hope to debug any problems if you can't see actual errors occurring, nor can we really help you without more info.  Why do you conclude it "breaks the other code".  What do you actually observe?

Comment: Any clue/suggestion on how to add a more detailed error logger?

Comment: I don't know what your run environment is, but usually I just start the program from the command line with `node somefile.js` and then I see all the logging right in the console that I started the program in.  If I need more info than that shows, then I either add `console.log()` statements to give me more info or I set a breakpoint in the debugger and step through parts of the code or inspect variables, etc...